# What is most efficient: Customized or adapted ViewControllers?

Tags: ios

As someone who is not a trained programmer I have had a lingering question in the back of my head for a few months now.  Say I want to present 5 separate ”sets” or views of information to the user, but where each ViewController needs a little bit of customization, like changing labels, even locations and the type of some UIElements..

An example would be to present statistics on different types of data (for example height, weight, heart rate etc.)  All the views have titles, but they are different, they have charts, but with different underlying types  (Int vs Double) and some views would have more statistics presented than others.

You be the judge of what “efficient” means e.g. speed or convenience or further customization in the future, or whatever.

What is better, is it to create a UIViewController subclass for each view, and duplicate some code, or create one VC with logic  like  IFTTT, arrays etc so that you can reuse part of the code?

Comment: Personally, I like questions like these, because they help us create better patterns that will make our code easier to maintain (or easier for others to maintain).

Comment: I don't. All answers are actually opinions and SO isn't supposed to be a discussion forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your viewConrollers have some 'logic code' common, i.e creating some statistics or setting up some information, that should reside in one parentViewController, and all should inherit that parent.

The UI customisation should of course be done in separately inherited UIViewControllers.

And you should almost never write one ViewController class having a huge section of if/else statements setting up their own UIs.

Doing the former will give your code a much more cleaner look and will provide more maintainability.

Almost every code that I've seen so far, people use this particular approach. A few exceptions where the 2 views are very closely linked and a simple if/else would fix their differences.

Comment: Ok, that is interesting. It is what I was hoping to hear.. But not what I expected.  I expected to hear: "Never duplicate code".  I am interested to see if anyone else have an opinion on this.

Comment: @karlml wait sorry. I think I missed the answer by a long shot. I thought all your viewControllers are different and have very little in common. Let me  reformat my answer really quick.

Comment: So I should "factor out" the common parts and have separate VC's for the remaining parts and call the common logic from there?

Comment: Exactly. The common part that you are moving to your parent ViewController, ideally it should only have to do with setting up the UI. If it is some non-UI code, it should be somewhere else, like a Utility class.

Answer (score 1):

I like to create a parent view controller (let's call it RootViewController) that all other view controller's inherit.  That way, if I need to do something that will affect them all, I can make it in one place.

For example:

(RootViewController.h)

```
@interface RootViewController : UIViewController {
    UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner;
    UIView *spinnerBkgd;
}

- (void) setSpinnerMessage:(NSString *)message;
- (void) showSpinner;
- (void) hideSpinner;

@end
```

(RootViewController.m)

```
#import "RootViewController.h"

@interface RootViewController () {
    BOOL spinnerAnimating;
    UILabel *spinnerLabel;
}

@end

@implementation RootViewController

- (void) viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    float longestDimension = self.view.frame.size.width;
    if (self.view.frame.size.width < self.view.frame.size.height)
        longestDimension = self.view.frame.size.height;

    UIView *spinnerParentView = self.navigationController.view;
    if (!spinnerParentView)
        spinnerParentView = self.view;

    spinnerBkgd = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:(CGRect){ 0, 0, longestDimension, longestDimension }];
    spinnerBkgd.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    spinnerBkgd.alpha = 0.0f;
    [spinnerParentView addSubview:spinnerBkgd];

    spinnerLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 400, 60)];
    spinnerLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    spinnerLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:18.0f];
    spinnerLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    [spinnerBkgd addSubview:spinnerLabel];

    spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
    spinner.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100);
    spinner.center = self.view.center;
    [spinnerBkgd addSubview:spinner];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(showSpinner)
                                                 name:JBB_SHOW_SPINNER
                                               object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(updateStatusMessage:)
                                                 name:JBB_UPDATE_STATUS_MESSAGE
                                               object:nil];
}

- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    spinnerAnimating = NO;

    [self resetInternalFrames];
}

- (void) setSpinnerMessage:(NSString *)message {
    spinnerLabel.text = message;
}

- (void) showSpinner {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        if (!spinnerAnimating) {
            spinnerLabel.text = @"";
            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.8f
                                  delay:0.2f
                                options: UIViewAnimationOptionAllowAnimatedContent
                             animations:^{
                                 spinnerBkgd.alpha = 0.6f;
                             }
                             completion:^(BOOL finished){
                                 //NSLog(@"show spinner");
                             }];


            [spinner startAnimating];

            spinnerAnimating = YES;
        }
    });
}

- (void) hideSpinner {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        //NSLog(@"hide spinner");
        spinnerBkgd.alpha = 0.0f;
        [spinner stopAnimating];
        spinnerLabel.text = @"";

        spinnerAnimating = NO;
    });
}

- (void) updateStatusMessage:(NSNotification*)notification {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self setSpinnerMessage:[notification.userInfo objectForKey:@"statusMessage"]];
    });
}

- (void) resetInternalFrames {
    spinner.center = self.view.center;
    spinnerLabel.center = (CGPoint) { self.view.center.x, self.view.center.y - 90 };
}

- (void) didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation {
    [self resetInternalFrames];
}

@end
```

With the above example, any view controller that subclasses RootViewController can take advantage of my full screen spinner (when loading content).

I also have started making "Base Cells" for collection views, which other "Cells" sub-class.  Often-times, there is common functionality that can be put into a base class that is shared by everything.  Anything that would require a condition (if (x is supported) then display y) needs to go into a specific subclass.  However, if it is something that will be in 2 or more subclasses, I will subclass the root, and make the other 2 sub-subclasses.

Rough example, with made up names:

```
RootCollectionViewCell:UICollectionViewCell
+-- RootScrollviewCollectionViewCell:RootCollectionViewCell
   +-- FriendCell:RootScrollviewCollectionViewCell
   +-- MediaCell:RootScrollviewCollectionViewCell
       +-- PhotosCell:MediaCell
       +-- VideosCell:MediaCell
+-- DetailCell:RootCollectionViewCell
+-- FeelingsCell:RootCollectionViewCell
```

This way, the photos and videos cells subclass mediacell, which subclasses my scrollview cell.  The rest just display content without a scrollview, so inherit from the root.

Comment: Thank you for this example! I will definitely start to think about ways I can factor out my code, your example is a good implementation of this.